# django-selectable populate AutocompleteSelectField on loading form

Tags: django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I succesfully implemented the django-selectable AutoCompleteSelectField in a simple form that lets you enter an note description and a corresponding domain category ( domain and foreign key picked from other Many-to-One relationship

See: most relevant code:

```
# MODEL
class Note(models.Model):
    notetext = models.TextField(default='nota')
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.notetext
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('note:note_detail', args= [self.id])

# FORM
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    domainselect = AutoCompleteSelectField(lookup_class= DomainLookup, label='Pick a domain category', required=True,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        domaintext = self.instance.domain.title
        self.fields['domainselect'].widget =  AutoCompleteSelectWidget(DomainLookup , { 'value': self.instance.domain.title  } )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.domain = self.cleaned_data['domainselect']
        return  super(NoteForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('notetext',)
        widgets = {
        'domain' : AutoCompleteSelectWidget(DomainLookup),   }

# VIEW
class EditNoteView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Note
    form_class = NoteForm
    success_url = "/note/"
    def get_queryset(self):
        base_qs = super(EditNoteView, self).get_queryset()
        return base_qs.filter()

    def get_object(self):
        object = get_object_or_404(Note,id=self.kwargs['id'])
        return object

# TEMPLATE
{% extends "base_sidebar.html" %}

{%block content%}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load selectable_tags %}
        {{ form.media.css }}
        {{ form.media.js }}

    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

Now, when an existing record is selected for editing via generic.edit.UpdateView in a Modelform, I want to populate the AutocompleteSelectField with the corresponding values ( domain description and id )  formerly saved into the database upon loading the form.

By overwriting the  **init**(self, *args, **kwargs) method of the NoteForm, I was able to get almost this far in the sense that the first HTML input field gets populated. 
However, the hidden input value gets set to the same value and pushing the save button results in posting a non valid form as if no domain category was selected.

Here's the page source that is sent back to the Browser:

```
<p><label for="id_domainselect_0">Pick a domain:</label> 
<input data-selectable-allow-new="false" data-selectable-type="text" data-selectable-url="/selectable/domain-domainlookup/" id="id_domainselect_0" name="domainselect_0" type="text" value="politics" />
<input data-selectable-type="hidden" id="id_domainselect_1" name="domainselect_1" type="hidden" value="politics" /></p>
```

I don't know how to change the context (by setting self.fields['domainselect'].widget) in order to get the title into the domainselect_0 input value and the corresponding pk into the hidden domainselect_1 input value. ?

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

After digging down into the django-selectable and Django code it appears the AutocompleteSelectWidget is based on the Django forms.MultiWidget class.
The Django MultiWidget accepts 1 single value (list) that is decomposed into the values corresponding to the respective 'subWidgets' through a mechanism implemented in a decompress method. ( see https://github.com/mlavin/django-selectable/blob/master/selectable/forms/widgets.py class SelectableMultiWidget ) 
So, all you have to do is assign a list containing title and id to the widget:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['domainselect'] = [self.instance.domain.title , self.instance.domain.id ]
```